# MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error. code: -32603

Tags: solidity, metamask

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZgCC.png

> console error img

Here is the code with the "Invalid user ID" warning:

```html
    function userInfoByAddress(address account) public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 userId = userids[account];
        require(userId > 0 && userId <= totalUsers, "Invalid user ID");
        return (userId);
    }

    function getUserBasicInfo(uint256 userId)
        public
        view
        returns (
            address,
            uint256,
            address,
            bool,
            bool,
            bool
        )
    {
        require(userId > 0 && userId <= totalUsers, "Invalid user ID");
        User storage user = users[userId];
        return (
            user.referer,
            userids[user.referer],
            user.account,
            user.disableDeposit,
            user.activate,
            user.autoReinvest
        );
    }

    function getUserDepositInfo(uint256 userId)
        public
        view
        returns (
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256
        )
    {
        require(userId > 0 && userId <= totalUsers, "Invalid user ID");
        User storage user = users[userId];
        return (user.totalDeposit, user.totalAllocated, user.totalWithdrawn);
    }

    function getUserPartnerInfo(uint256 userId)
        public
        view
        returns (uint256[] memory)
    {
        require(userId > 0 && userId <= totalUsers, "Invalid user ID");
        User storage user = users[userId];
        return (user.partners);
    }
    
    function getUserBonusInfo(uint256 userId)
        public
        view
        returns (uint256, uint256)
    {
        require(userId > 0 && userId <= totalUsers, "Invalid user ID");
        User storage user = users[userId];
        return (user.totalBonus, user.directBonus);
    }

    function getUserLevelInfo(uint256 userId) public view returns (uint256) {
        require(userId > 0 && userId <= totalUsers, "Invalid user ID");
        User storage user = users[userId];
        return (user.level);
    }

    function getUserPartnerTree(uint256 userId)
        public
        view
        returns (uint256[] memory)
    {
        require(userId > 0 && userId <= totalUsers, "Invalid user ID");
        uint256[] memory partnerTree = getPartnerTree(userId);
        return partnerTree;
    }
```

**I am facing this error, but when I using browser extension Metamask Wallet, even this error I can proceed and go through my transaction. Only in mobile Metamask Wallet or TokenPocket, it show Transaction Error: Internal JSON-RPC Error.**

Here is the frontend JS:

```
async function getApproval() {
    const userAddress = window.userWalletAddress;
    const amount = web3.utils.toBN("115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935");
    try {
        disableScreen();
        const tx = await contract.methods.approve(spender, amount).send({ from: userAddress });
        enableScreen();
        if (!tx) {
            document.getElementById("dashboardModalTitle").innerText = "Error Engaging";
            document.getElementById("dashboardModalBody").innerText = "You Need to Approve to continue!";
            jQuery("#dashboardModal").modal("toggle");
            return
        }

        document.getElementById("approveBtn").removeEventListener("click", getApproval)
        document.getElementById("engageBtn").addEventListener("click", setEngage)
        document.getElementById("connectwalletcont").style.display = "none"
        document.getElementById("dashboardcont").style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("approvetokencont").style.display = "none"
    } catch (error) {
        enableScreen();
        document.getElementById("dashboardModalTitle").innerText = "Error Engaging";
        document.getElementById("dashboardModalBody").innerText = "You Need to Approve to continue!";
        jQuery("#dashboardModal").modal("toggle");

    }
}
```